# Angular Tree menu

Tags: angularjs

Working with angularjs, I am trying Angular Treeview plugin.

But when i try it on my local environment, it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">

    <div>
      <input type="button" value="TREE MODEL 1" data-ng-click="roleList = roleList1" /> <input type="button" value="TREE MODEL 2" data-ng-click="roleList = roleList2" />
    </div>

    <div style="margin:10px 0 30px 0; padding:10px; background-color:#EEEEEE; border-radius:5px; font:12px Tahoma;">
      <span><b>Selected Node</b> : {{currentNode.roleName}}</span>
    </div>

    <div
      data-angular-treeview="true"
      data-tree-model="roleList"
      data-node-id="roleId"
      data-node-label="roleName"
      data-node-children="children" >
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And Called the angular.treeview.js script & angular.treeview.css file..

I am getting this error in my local dev console:

> CONSOLE has ReferenceError: angular is not defined })( angular );

Comment: Their fiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/

Comment: Locally are you getting any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Yes... CONSOLE has
ReferenceError: angular is not defined
 

})( angular );

Comment: Fixed spelling and grammar and improved format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you are loading this script - I recommend following the treeviews suggest installation method. So load all the scripts - in this case you would have copies of their css and js files locally - and replace the angular reference with however you are loading it (CDN or locally or whatever).

This is probably in your header -

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="YourAngularScript.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/angular.treeview.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/angular.treeview.css">
```

Notice **angular is loaded first**. Then when you create your angular app module (or whatever module is using this as a dependency), add it as a dependency to that app module like so:

```
  angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview']);
```

Just make sure you replace the script references I used here with references to the real scripts/css files.

Your error `CONSOLE has ReferenceError: angular is not defined })( angular );` is the treeview script does not have a reference to angular yet.